# How to fix the totalCount of the list returned by the list method of the GORM query for a specified Criteria?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am getting the wrong result for `totalCount` property of the list returned from the list function of the GORM query.

I think this is due to the issue that it also includes the duplicate results. The results returned in the list are correct but the count seems to be wrong.

How can I fix it?

I tried following but it does not work:

```
trace.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.PROJECTION)
```

Following is my GORM query:

```
    def trace = Trace.createCriteria()

    def results = trace.list(max:max, offset:offset) {
        createAlias('module','mod', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('symbol','sym', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('fault', 'fault',CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('fault.report', 'report', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('fault.tgmap', 'tg', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
        createAlias('tg.traceGroup16','tr', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)        
        projections
        {
            property('fault.id')
            property('tr.geckId')
            property('report.email')
            property('fault.ver')
            property('fault.shortOs')
            property('fault.faultDate')
            property('frameNumber')
            property('mod.module')
            property('sym.symbol')
            groupProperty 'fault.pid'
            groupProperty 'report.file'
        }
        // Handle Unknown module case
        if (module.length() > 0 && symbol.length() > 0 && module != symbol)
        {
            and
            {
                like('mod.module', '%' + module + '%')
                like('sym.symbol', '%' + symbol + '%')
            }

        }
        else if (module.length() > 0 && symbol.length() > 0 && module == symbol)
        {
            or 
            {
                like('mod.module', '%' + module + '%')
                like('sym.symbol', '%' + symbol + '%')
            }
        }
        else if (module.length() > 0)
        {
            like('mod.module', '%' + module + '%')
        }
        else if (symbol.length() > 0)
        {
            like('sym.symbol', '%' + symbol + '%')
        }           
        order("fault.faultDate", "desc")
}
```

Comment: Can you add the actual query implementation?

Comment: Is LEFT_JOIN necessary?

Comment: @dmahapatro   Yes, LEFT_JOIN is necessary, I do not want to use the default INNER_JOIN. The results returned by this query are correct but the totalCount is far greater than what rows are actually returned.

Comment: This is how hibernate works for one-to-many relations, database will return more rows is such case (you get this number) and application will merge rows for the same group object in memory. You can use "projections {  countDistinct('id')  }" to get distinct count on specific object

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty annoying problem - you can filter out the duplicates using a `distinct` projection, but you'll find pagination is messed up. Usually I end up with an approach like this:

1. Query to get the totalCount using `countDistinct`
2. Query again to get the *distinct ids* for a range of rows (e.g. rows 1 - 10) using a `distinct('id')` projection
3. Create a `PagedResultList` instance, and query again using `DomainClass.getAll(ids)`
4. Set the `totalCount` and the list returned from `DomainClass.getAll(ids)` manually on your `PagedResultList`

You can see some examples using this approach in the excellent [Filter Pane](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-filterpane) and [Quick Search](https://github.com/tadodotcom/grails-quick-search) plugins.

Not ideal, but it does work and for most use cases the performance impact of doing 4 queries (instead of 2) isn't so bad.